# To know if a unit is normal to a plane. where am I mistaken??

Tags: vector-spaces

I am preparing an exam for next week and reviewing all exams I come to this question:

Which one of the following vectors in R3 is a unit vectorthat is normal to the plane

with gral equation x-y+√2z=5  I have fours solutions but I know the answer is (-1/2,

1/2, -1/√2). I checked if its magnitud is one and it is, so I know if I am not mistaken

that for a vector to be normal to another vector their dot product has to be 0, so (1,-

1,√2).(-1/2,1/2,-1/√2) I do not get 0 but -2 as a result?? So can anyone tell me what I

am doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector $\,\left(1,-1,\sqrt 2\right)\,$ itself is normal to the plane $\,x-y+\sqrt 2\,z=0\,$ ...! This is obvious from the vectorial (inner product) formula of a plane, so clearly the vector $\,\left(-\frac{1}{2}\,,\,\frac{1}{2}\,,\,-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)\,$ is also normal to the plane as it is a scalar multiple of the first vector...

Comment: Yes, but my question is , shouldnt the scalar product of the two vectors be 0?

Comment: But you're taking the scalar product of two *paralell* vectors! Of course it won't ever be zero (unless you have the zero vector, of course). Again, for the plane $\,Ax+By+Cz+D=0\,$ , the vector $\,(A,B,C)\,$ is *always* normal to the plane...

Comment: ok, so..I know that the vector (A,B,C) is normal to the plane, how do I know then if the vector (-1/2, 1/2, -1/√2) is normal to the plane ?  as far as I know this happens when (x,y,z)*(A,B,C)=0 right?

Comment: No! That vector *must* be a scalar multiple of $\,(A,B,C)\,$ , and the only thing you must worry about, and you *already* did, is that that vector is unitary.

Comment: ok, sweet, so to know if a vector is perpinduclar to a plane, this vector has to be a scalar multiple of the nornal vector to the plane given by (A,B,C) so 1/-0.5=-2 and -1/0.5=-2....sweeet thanks a lot !! :)

Comment: Yup, this time is right...and as you can see, pretty simple when you have the rectangular formula of a plane. For the (geometric)vectorial form a little more work is necessary.